# implement jsp cache at "html level"

Tags: java, jsp, caching

I would like to implement a jsp cache at "html level". My idea is:

```
for each request{
  if(exists("/cache/<product_id>/<product_name>.html")){
    response "/cache/product/1234/cat.html"
  }else{
    response database.getCat("1234")
  }
}

exists(String path){
   if(!file(path)){
     return false;
   }else{
      if((currentDate = file(path).createdAt) > CACHE_TIME){
         return false
      }else{
          return true
      }
   }
}
```

So, as you can see only go to database (or another heavy process) if the page was not showed since  CACHE_TIME

Example:

User 1 go to http://mysite.com/products/1234/cat.jsp
Systems go to the database and generates an html file (products-1234-cat.html)
User 1 see the page
Immediately comes User 2 and go to the same url
System sees that a cache exists, so response using products-1234-cat.html (no database, no heavy process).

How can I implement this?

I hope I was clear with what I want

Comment: Just to clarify - you're talking about a server-side cache on the application server?

Comment: @home yes I am, maybe tweaking something on app server.

Comment: Do you have a web server guarding your app server (e.g. apache http server)... this might be the easiest way to implement caching?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache, you will be better of using mem_cache module or similar
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html

but if you really have a good reason to use an application level caching you should do it differently. The way you want to do it will be not thread safe unless you add some extra logic (i mean a racing condition when creating those cached html files).

I'd add a new custom tag to JSP tag library (customtag:cache) and wrap your content into this tag. Depending on the cache ttl or its state (warm, cold) I would render either the actual content from within the cache tag or its cached version which could be stored in a HashMap.